# How to cast / use Activity context in a Broadcast Receiver, started from AlarmManager

Tags: android

I have a daily alarm that should contain a text that I can only get from Activity Context - the activity generates a key from the user's settings to get specifically generated info for the given day.

The notification is started from BootReceiver and from AlarmManager every day at 10 AM even if the app is not running.

How do I cast the BroadcastReceiver context to an activity, or run the activity invisibly in order to make use of its methods?

This is how I set the alarms:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

This is the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class PushNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context context;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    this.context = context;

    String notificationTitle = intent.getExtras().getString("notificationTitle");
    String notificationText;
    boolean dailyNotification = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("dailyNotification ", false);
    int requestCode = intent.getExtras().getInt("requestCode");

    if(dailyNotification ) {

        Log.d("DAILY","DAILY");

        // HERE IS WHERE I NEED A BUNCH OF METHODS FROM THE ACTIVITY TO GENERATE THE TITLE AND THE TEXT FOR THE NOTIFICATION
        notificationTitle = "ASD";
        notificationText = "asd";
    } else {
         notificationText = intent.getExtras().getString("notificationText");
    }

    String soundResource = "android.resource://com.asdqwe.asd/raw/tone";
    Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(soundResource);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentTitle(notificationTitle)//
            .setContentText(notificationText)//
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)//
            .setSound(soundUri)//
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.app_icon));//

    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MyActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(543, mBuilder.build());


} // End of onReceive
```

Comment: Can't you calculate the key from your receiver?

Comment: It needs lots of methods and fields from the Activity

Comment: I guess I could convert the user data to a file that I can read from, but that sounds complex...

Comment: Can you give us an example? I don't understand why the activity is needed here

Comment: The data to be displayed is in a hashmap, held in the activity. The user size and weight are also held in fields in the activity.

Comment: You can start a transparent activity from the broadcast receiver. Send notification from there. Use theme of activity as android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"

Comment: so far so good, but how will the activity return info to the receiver so the receiver starts the notification with it?

Comment: I think there is a design problem here: you can't do that. When broadcast receivers is woken up your activity could be not loaded at all so you can get data only from shared preferences for example. In addition the receiver should do only short work, the best thing is to start a intent service to do the work, send notifications, and so on.

Comment: Start a new activity from receiver. Then send notification from activity and finish it.

Comment: @greywolf82 Are u saying we can't start activity from receiver?

Comment: @berserk Yes you can, but I don't know if in this case it's the right thing to do.

Comment: Guys I think that Im going to record all the user data in a json on the storage so I can access it from the receiver in order to generate the key. Is this a good plan? No need to use the activity then

Comment: @greywolf82 I also think there is no need of activity for calculations. It can be done in receiver.